Clickhouse query isssues
I'm trying to do a complicated query in Clikchouse and I'm struggling to see where my error is.
I have three tables within Clickhouse:

jump_news_sentiment.news_sentiment_after with columns: assetid, date, agg_sentiment, agg_sentiment_rw, and n
jump_news_sentiment.news_sentiment_before with columns: assetid, date, agg_sentiment, agg_sentiment_rw, and n
jump_news_sentiment.date_next with columns: date, and date_next

What I try to achieve:

Prepare sentiment data by shifting dates forward in the table news_sentiment_after
Combine sentiment data from before and after specific dates for each asset, handling nulls and summing up values as necessary.
Further process the merged data by filtering based on intervals defined in another table and aggregating sentiment scores and counts within these intervals for each asset.

The query that I use is:
WITH shifted_dates AS (
        SELECT 
            assetid, 
            dateAdd(day, 1, date) AS date, 
            agg_sentiment, 
            agg_sentiment_rw, 
            n
        FROM jump_news_sentiment.news_sentiment_after
    ), merged_data AS (
        SELECT 
            coalesce(b.assetid, a.assetid) AS assetid, 
            coalesce(b.date, a.date) AS date, 
            coalesce(b.agg_sentiment, 0) + coalesce(a.agg_sentiment, 0)  AS agg_sentiment,
            coalesce(b.agg_sentiment_rw, 0) + coalesce(a.agg_sentiment_rw, 0) AS agg_sentiment_rw,
            coalesce(a.n, 0) + coalesce(b.n, 0) AS n
        FROM shifted_dates a
        FULL OUTER JOIN jump_news_sentiment.news_sentiment_before b USING (date, assetid)
    ),
    aggregated_data AS (
        SELECT 
            m.assetid AS assetid,
            max(m.date) AS date,
            sum(m.agg_sentiment) AS agg_sentiment,
            sum(m.agg_sentiment_rw) AS agg_sentiment_rw,
            sum(m.n) AS n
        FROM merged_data m
        JOIN jump_news_sentiment.date_next e ON m.date > e.date AND m.date <= e.date_next
        GROUP BY m.assetid, e.date_next
    )
    SELECT * FROM aggregated_data;

However, when I do this I get the following error:
JOIN  merged_data AS __table2 ALL INNER JOIN jump_news_sentiment.date_next AS __table6 ON (__table2.date > __table6.date) AND (__table2.date <= __table6.date_next) join expression contains column from left and right table.


try to use EXPLAIN SYNTAX

This means ClickHouse analysis that the expression reference columns from both sides of the JOIN, which is not supported for the JOIN type.
The error typically means, ClickHouse is struggle with columns in both tables being joined due to how the columns are being referenced in the query. I think the cause might be use range conditions (m.date > e.date AND m.date <= e.date_next) in the ON clause of the INNER JOIN.
To better understand the challenge, can you provide table DDL and some small set of sample data for news_sentiment_after, news_sentiment_before, and date_next tables ?
Please also share the ClickHouse version by running SELECT version()
